# Не эквивалентные повороты

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не могу понять, почему эти две строки работают по-разному:

```
transform.Rotate(-90 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

transform.eulerAngles = 
    new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x + (-90 * Time.deltaTime), 0, 0);
```

Проблема видна на видео: [Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StMePPK0uM0&feature=youtu.be)

Где тот что нормально крутиться то через Rotate

Comment: Добавьте пример в виде скриншота для будущих пользователей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не с этим ли связано (относительно чего вращение)?

[Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)

```
public void Rotate(Vector3 eulers, Space relativeTo = Space.Self);
```

> If relativeTo is not specified or set to Space.Self the rotation is applied **around the transform's local axes**. If relativeTo is set to Space.World the rotation is applied around the world x, y, z axes.

---

По установке углов  eulerAngles, кстати, есть такая ремарка:

> Don't increment them, as it will fail when the angle exceeds 360 degrees.

Comment: даже смена Space не помогла, а на счет последнего, даже если при этом сначало угол делить с остатком на 360 т.е. что бы начать новый круг, та же проблема

Comment: Видео выглядит так, как будто сфера куда-то упёрлась. Похоже на фиксацию угла в каком-то положении. Какие при этом углы - можно выяснить?  Не зря пишут `Use Transform.Rotate instead`. Как выглядит код `угол делить с остатком на 360` - учитывается переход через 360 и через 0 к отрицательным?

Comment: transform1.eulerAngles.x % (-360) - уперлось в 270, т.е. -90, если делить с остатком без минуса то упреться 90, при этом будет изменяться на +- 1, т.е. будет проскакивать 89-91, но в среднем будет на 90 градусах.

Comment: Это что-то типа "Gimbal Lock" на полюсах. Как я уже сказал, не зря они требуют Rotate использовать для постоянного вращения [ссылка](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html)

Answer (score 1):

для вращения используй только `Quaternion`, `Vector3` - только для установки значений (чтобы было удобно читать)
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html

Comment: ранее так и думал, просто параметр w напугал, никогда не мог найти о нем в интернете

Comment: @k0vpack меньше размышляй о всех четырех значениях - ни одно из них не удобочитаемо

Comment: просто сколько уже смотрю, читаю, ничего о них не понимаю.

Comment: используй методы которые в нем объявлены + какой-нибудь lerp